# Vim - change operation from current cursor till last character of occurence

Tags: vim

Firstly, I want to replace a text in vim using `c` operator. 
for example, from this line

`android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

into

`well.just.another.package.TextInputLayout`

effectively.

Well, I know I could do `c[count]w` or maybe `c/\.\cte`, but I feel vim could do better and smarter.

Secondly, did anyone know how to change operation using search or `c/`, for example:

> a `word` to change, and also still had a `word` to change, but not
>   this `word` and afterward.

into

> a `sound` to change, and also still had a `sound` to change, but not
>   this `word` and afterward.

using `c/`, but the operation will only change all the `word` into `sound` except the last occurrence.

Thank you.

Comment: That's two questions.

Comment: @romainl  should I split it into 2 questions instead?. I created it like this because I'd thought the first solution could be applicable to the second example.

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat. For this example, `ctT` would do but it looks like you expect some kind of standard that works in all cases... there isn't one.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Well, I also had thought  the same way as you do. Actually I was just hoping to get a solution that could be applicable to both cases. But it seemed impossible, right?

Comment: @Nanangarsyad - I don't know of one but don't take that as a reference though ;)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, for the first question you can type `ctT` (or more generally `$bc0`) then write the missing text.

For the second question, you want to replace the first two occurrences of `word` with `sound`, this can be done with the command:

```
call feedkeys("yyq") | s/word/sound/gc
```

**Edit:** A way to do the replacement with the `c` operator would be to search for `word` then type `cwsound<esc>`, then repeatedly type <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: Well just like what I said in the comment in my question. I was just trying to know a way to do both of the task. To be precise I was hoping to know how to change all occurrence except the last one using `c/` operation, like what I stated in my question. Seemed it's impossible to do right?

Comment: @Nanang, I included a replacement using `c` operator.

Answer (score 0):

On the first question:
You could always do: `%s/android\..*widget/well.just.another.package/g`

With the option to append `c` to the command to make it interactive

I don't know if it's more efficient, but that's not for me to decide.